# Create MS Visual C++ DLL project out of existing sources

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

My goal is to compile existing C++ classes (legacy code, stored in a set of `*.h` files) into a DLL so that it can be further integrated into a C# application.

For that purpose, it seems best to use MS Visual Studio. I have no experience with this environment, so I tried the naive approach found on MSDN and other SO answers:

- File | New | Project from existing code
- selected Visual C++
- selected file location that is base for include references used in those `.h` files
- specified a project name
- let the wizard find and add all C++ files below the directory
- selected "Use Visual Studio" for build, with project type "Dynamically Linked Library (DLL) project"
- checked none of the checkboxes below (ATL, MFC, CLR)
- specified `.` dir in the "Include search paths (/I)" in Debug settings
- checked "Same as Debug configuration" in "Release settings"
- clicked Finish button

This creates couple of VS files in the directory:

```
mylibrary.sln
mylibrary.vcxproj
mylibrary.vcxproj.filters
mylibrary.vcxproj.user
```

With a project created this way, I press `F6` or select `Build` | `Rebuild solution` from the menu.

Then I expect the build to produce the `.dll` file somewhere, but it does not appear. Only these files appear:

```
.vs/mylibrary/v15/.suo
.vs/mylibrary/v15/Browse.VC.db
.vs/mylibrary/v15/Browse.VC.opendb
.vs/mylibrary/v15/ipch/AutoPCH/efad7c74cd39331b/EXAMPLE.ipch
Debug/mylibrary.log
Debug/mylibrary.tlog/mylibrary.lastbuildstate
```

Next, I decided to try creating a fresh new library project, just to observe the differences to get some hints, but that did not help - there were too many differences, even in the file structure...

My questions are:

- is my choice of MS Visual C++ a good one for given purpose?
- if so, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't compile.h files into libraries. And you cannot directly use C++ code from C#. You should (if anything) be looking at how to use C++/CLI.

Comment: do you mean that the suffix does matter for MS Visual C++ ? I can try to split the code into `.cc` and `.h` but I just expected this should not be necessary

Comment: The suffix certainly matters in some circumstances, but the issue is more that the types of content of .h and .cpp files are normally very different.

Comment: in my case, the `.h` files contain complete code including implementation; not very typical, I know, but works fine on linux

Comment: Yes, but you need to #include those headers in something in order for VS  to generate an executable/library - VS does not directly compile .h files. If it is working on Linux without you doing that, then your project design on Linux is wrong too.

Comment: looks like you are right, for MSVC it really does matter; and it is apparently enough to create single cpp file that just includes the headers. Thanks!

Comment: would the downvoters please care to explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: The canonical solution to making native code available to .NET is to wrap the functionality and expose a .NET interface. The standard tool for that is C++/CLI. While fairly straight forward to use, you will have to learn about the details. [C++/CLI in Action](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1932394818) is a useful guide.

Comment: @IInspectable sure that's the goal I am trying to achieve

Comment: You won't get closer to that goal by compiling your code into an unmanaged library. Instead, create a mixed-mode assembly, that can contain both your unmanaged, native code, as well as your .NET-consumable interfaces.

Comment: @IInspectable it already works for me, the only bad thing is that I need 2 DLLs on PATH; but your idea sounds interesting, I will explore how to do it, thanks

Comment: If you need the location of your modules to be on the PATH environment variable, you are doing it wrong. You need to install **all** your dependencies into your program's install location. (There are ways around this, but unless you have a *very good* reason not to deploy your dependencies into the install location, just do it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your steps are probably correct and I think that the right approach to use the code from a C# application. You definitely can call a C++ library from C# by importing the methods.

You missed only to export the methods that you want to use from your library. try using __declspec(dllexport) with these methods. please check this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx.

Also, the output should be at the build folder, not the source code folder

Answer (score 0):

Compiling `.h` files into libraries is ok, the compiler does not care - however, the UI does.
Still, you can tweak this by directly editing the `.vcxproj` file.

While doing so, make sure that the `<ClCompile>` sections contain:

```
  <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
```

Note that you can use commandline for building the DLL project:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" -target:Clean,Build
```

(this assumes that your current directory is the one with your `.vcxproj`)